# Cannot download png files from generic artifactory repo

Tags: png, jpeg, artifactory, artifact

I'm getting 404 - not found error when trying to download pn from a generic artifactory repo using artifactory api. But can be downloaded directly from Artifactory UI.
Is this a known fact?
Or is there a workaround?

When using powershell webclient
"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

When using postman GET
https://artifactory url/artifactory/testpng/test-1.png

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem when attempting to download or upload png files when using the API correctly.
The best way to work with Artifactory Repositories is by following the "Set Me Up" tool in the UI, under **Applications->Artifacts**, and clicking on the "Set Me Up" button in the top right corner and choosing the relevant repository.

The correct command for a Local Generic Repository should be:
$curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API_KEY>" -O "https://ARTIFACTORY-URL/artifactory/example-generic-local/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"

If this still doesn't work for you, share your version* of artifactory and if you are a SaaS/On-prem

** To get the version, use the REST API:
$curl -u user:password https://ARTIFACTORY-URL/artifactory/api/system/version

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. Simply I have deployed a 'png' and a 'txt' in the repo and tried 'URL to File:' given in general view on a browser.
for txt:  It got it open in the browser
for Png: 404, Not Found :-(

Its On-Prem.

Version info:

'{
    "version": "7.37.15",
    "revision": "73715900",
    "addons": [
        "build",
        ...
    ],
    "license": "..",
    "entitlements": {
        "EVENT_BASED_PULL_REPLICATION": false,
        "SMART_REMOTE_TARGET_FOR_EDGE": false,
        "REPO_REPLICATION": true,
        "MULTIPUSH_REPLICATION": false
    }
}'